# How long do applicants ususaly have to accept a PhD offer? How committing is it?

Tags: application, united-kingdom

I'm currently and full-time employment and planning a career switch. I've identified a doctorate programme as something I'd be interested in doing and so consequently I'm going on full steam with the application processes. However, I am not yet 100% sure a PhD is something I *should* do. I anticipate a bunch of life changes in the next several months and I'd like to generally keep myself open to opportunities which don't require a few-year-long commitment.

I want to plan the timing of my applications, as well as prepare mentally for potentially having to make that commitment. And hence my question:

**How much time would I usually have between receiving an PhD offer and having to accept it?** I am aware of that time when it comes to normal employment (approx. 2 weeks) but I don't know how that works in academia (and British academia in particular). Surely, they must be mindful of the fact that many programmes have different application deadlines and hence to make an informed decision one would want to hear from most of them... Although, must they?

Comment: What discipline do you intend to enter? For example, in physics, funding is controlled by the research council, STFC. As they say on their [website](http://www.stfc.ac.uk/funding/studentships/studentship-terms-conditions-guidance/statistics-and-questionnaires/stfc-funded-phd-students/acceptance-of-phd-studentships/): "STFC strongly recommends that prospective students should not be placed under undue pressure by departments to accept PhD places within short timescales. Therefore students should not be compelled to accept offers of PhD places prior to 31 March each year."

Comment: @NatalieHogg Engineering / Environmental Science

Comment: Are you applying for funded projects? If so, I expect the system will be similar to that in physics; the funding application deadline is the end of January and you have until the end of March to sort through your offers and make a decision. If you have your own funding, it's more likely you will be free to apply at any time of year and specify when you would like to start.

Comment: In the US if you are offered funding there is a nearly universal deadline of April 15th for programs starting in the fall...but it is my understanding that this is specific to the US and the UK/Europe doesn't participate in this rule. I'll just leave this here if people come across this regarding the US instead of the UK: http://cgsnet.org/april-15-resolution